# Фразеологизм "себя изжил". Его употребление

Tags: фразеология

подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли построено предложение с фразеологизмом "себя изжил": "мне всего 20 лет, но я напрочь себя изжил".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Себя изжил" - здесь это примерно соответствует "морально устарел". В принципе-то так сказать можно, но, боюсь, здесь будет не совсем тот смысл, на который рассчитывал автор.

Очень сомнительно-, что в двадцать лет человеку свойственно подобное мироощущение. 
Так что менять скорее всего придется. Но нужен контекст, чтобы понять, что хотел сказать автор.